# Как работает этот action yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Подскажите пожалуйста последовательность работы этого экшена...

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $user = $model->signup();
            if ($user) {
                if ($model->shouldBeActivated()) {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('alert', [
                        'body' => Yii::t(
                            'frontend',
                            'Your account has been successfully created. Check your email for further instructions.'
                        ),
                        'options' => ['class'=>'alert-success']
                    ]);
                } else {
                    Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user);
                }
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему это стандартный метод Yii2, чуть измененный, если GET запрос, выводит форму регистрации, если попадает POST запрос, то идет валидация данных:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
```

Потом создание пользователя:

```
$user = $model->signup();
```

Если нужно подтвердить регистрацию:

```
if ($model->shouldBeActivated()) {
```

То выводим сообщение что проверь email, если не нужно подтверждать - авторизуем.

Всё.